# Is it possible to use an additional HAT with the Raspberry Pi PoE HAT

Tags: hat, poe

I recently got a [Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/) and the official [Raspberry Pi PoE HAT](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-hat/). It is powering it from my switch fine but I am wondering if it is possible to also use an additional HAT with it?

The PoE HAT seem to allow pins to pass all the way through the PCB, but they are not long enough to attach a second HAT. I would like to a 1-wire HAT to do temperature sensor monitoring.

Is there something I can do / buy to add a second HAT?

Thanks!

[image: Photo of Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ with PoE HAT]

Answer (score 6):

You can buy stackable headers, which you could solder to the PoE HAT.

[image]

You could probably use without soldering as the PoE HAT seems to make no use of the Pi GPIO.

Any HAT mounted on top of the PoE HAT would impede the fan airflow, but as there is little evidence a fan is required this may not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I think it should be possible to push the stacking header all the way through the header on the PoE HAT without resoldering it, providing the pins aren't too big.
But I would then need to extend the length of the PoE header pins and get longer spacers. I will give it a go and report back.

Answer (score 6):

*OR*, you could use just a [PoE Splitter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B074Y6M67F/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which is half the price of a PoE Hat and avoids the issue of trying to stack multiple hats on top of each other. I paid £9.90 for the GB version of the PoE Splitter.  The same company sells a 10/100 speed version, so check you are buying the GB version before clicking "buy"-

[image: PoE Splitter]

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's possible.

The headers on the POE hat are passthrough style, but the pins on the Pi are too short to pass through them, so you need to extend the Pi's GPIO header, in turn this means you also need to extend the Pi's POE header.

Various vendors sell kits for doing this, for example

https://thepihut.com/products/4-40-pin-pin-extra-tall-header-push-fit-version-poe-hat-set

https://store.uputronics.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=110